# Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol - get user agent Stylesheet

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to retrieve user agent stylesheet using Chrome remote debugging protocol, but it is only returning regular stylesheet.
What I have done so far:
I have added listener on CSS.styleSheetAdded event and in this it is just returning regular stylesheet. 
Chrome dev tools also is a web app and there I can see user agent stylesheet.
I am not sure what I am missing here. Looking at the protocol it seems I have done everything correctly, but it doesn't work.
Can anyone please help, how to get user agent stylesheet?

Thanks.

Comment: You could always try and [listen on the remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#alpha) to see what DevTools actually do.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I did exactly that and in the websocket could not find any message exchange related to the user agent stylesheet. I can see few CSS.styleSheetAdded messages but all the origin values are "regular".

Comment: I suppose that since DevTools are rendered using Chrome, they have access to the UA stylesheet (as it also applies to them). Doesn't answer how to access it from your code. It also makes me wonder how remote debugging works across versions with incompatible UA stylesheets.

Comment: I think I figure out, the dev tools is using CSS.getMatchedStylesForNode when we click on any html tag say any 'div' for example, at that time it calls CSS.getMatchedStylesForNode and in the result I can see origin="user-agent". I think I will figure out the actual code from here. Thanks Xan